# Json full response in Json object or String

Tags: java, json

hi I am using okhttp for getting my data from the server and I am getting the response by `response.body().string()` that is printing full data. But when i am converting the response to `jsonobject` or String(Storing in the  variable) and printing data it is not displaying full data of the response.i am unable to display

```
"id": 1,
"user_id": 1,
"first_name": "hhhh",
"last_name": "Thakur",
```

while other is working fine
My json data in form

```
{
"customers": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "first_name": "hhhh",
        "last_name": "Thakur",
        "website": "",
        "status": 0,
        "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00",
        "customer_info": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00"
            }
        ],
        "customer_address": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "name": "hhhh Thakur",
                "address": "V.PO Chadwal Distt Kathua, Teh Hiranagar  Jammu, Jammu and Kashmir in",
                "city": "Shimla",
                "state": "Himachal Pradesh",
                "zip": "171004",
                "country": "India",
                "fax": "06723",
                "type": 1,
                "as_ship": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "name": "Neha Sharma",
                "address": "V.PO Chadwal Distt Kathua, Teh Hiranagar  Jammu, Jammu and Kashmir in",
                "city": "India",
                "state": "Jammu and Kashmir",
                "zip": "180012",
                "country": "India",
                "fax": "664984",
                "type": 2,
                "as_ship": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "first_name": "arun",
        "last_name": "kumar",
        "website": "www.isitwa.com",
        "status": 0,
        "created": "2017-10-11T10:14:38+00:00",
        "customer_info": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "customer_id": 2,
                "created": "2017-10-11T10:14:38+00:00"
            }
        ],
        "customer_address": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "customer_id": 2,
                "name": "",
                "address": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "zip": "",
                "country": "",
                "fax": "",
                "type": 1,
                "as_ship": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-11T10:14:38+00:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "customer_id": 2,
                "name": "",
                "address": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "zip": "",
                "country": "",
                "fax": "",
                "type": 2,
                "as_ship": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-11T10:14:38+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }

]}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That's because your JSON is invalid... Paste your JSON codes here, https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer , it will allow you to manipulate the formating, and take a better look into it...

I'm not an expert in Java but listing a nested array ( no matter, JSON or plain array ) can be done in two ways:

```
foreach ( $array as $item) {

    foreach ( $item as $key => $data) {
        echo $data;
    }

}

for ( $i=0; $i < $array.lenght(); $i++ ) {

    for ( $j=0; $j < $array.lenght-1; $j++) {
        print_r $array[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

Using foreach method is better if you don't know how long, or nested your array is...

Answer (score -1):

Your json data is not well formatted ,try to print below one:

```
{
"a": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "",
        "b": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00"
            }
        ],
        "c": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "b":[{
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "",
        "b": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00"
            }
        ],
        "c": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Comment: This is my actual json data

Comment: if its works as you want ,try to build Json like this

Comment: "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "first_name": "hhhh",
        "last_name": "Thakur",
        "website": "",
        "status": 0,
        "created": "2017-10-10T07:29:45+00:00"   is not viewing while priting

Comment: at end you are missing ' } '